Azure Devops Trigger from anotherproject and repo
In REPO A on project A - yaml files of pipeline (central project for them)
In Repo B on project B - Pipeline tab and code deployment location (IaaC let say).
pool:
  name: Pool_name

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Repo-A
    endpoint: Endpoint
    name: Project-A/Repo-A
    ref: main
    type: git
    trigger: none
  - repository: Repo-B
    endpoint: Endpoint
    name: Project-B/Repo-B
    ref: main
    type: git
    trigger:
    - main

stages:
- stage: stage-1
  displayName: stage-1
  jobs:
  - job: job-1
  displayName: job-1
  steps:
  - checkout: Repo-A
  - checkout: Repo-B
  - script: script-testing

As described in MS documentation, my trigger should work - Define a repositories resource
.
I have tried to set triggers, ref's with different properties but nothing is workig. Configuration
with
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main

also was tested. Nothing has changed.
What I want to achieve is to trigger this pipeline located in repo A to run when main of Repo-B will be updated.
They are in the same ADO Organization, on different projects. Same endpoint use for both projects.

What exactly does it mean nothing is working? Is there any error? The pipeline isn't triggered?

complete PR to repo-b is not triggering the pipeline. There is no error. Nothing happens.
But if I set trigger: - main on repo-a it will work on it. Just Repo-b trigger is not working

Pipelines started to work as expected after deleting the Endpoint.
Working config:
pool:
  name: Pool_name

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Repo-A
    name: Project-A/Repo-A
    ref: main
    type: git
    trigger: none
  - repository: Repo-B
    name: Project-B/Repo-B
    ref: main
    type: git
    trigger:
    - main

stages:
- stage: stage-1
  displayName: stage-1
  jobs:
  - job: job-1
  displayName: job-1
  steps:
  - checkout: Repo-A
  - checkout: Repo-B
  - script: script-testing


There seems to be a few issues with your pipeline triggers:

repository: Repo-A is duplicated. repository is the name used to reference the repository in the checkout step, so it should be unique
trigger: none will probably disable the CI trigger - is this intentional?

Try the following:
pool:
  name: Pool_name

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: RepoA # Alias/name used in the checkout step. It doesn't have to match the repository name
    endpoint: Endpoint
    name: Project-A/Repo-A # Project/repository name
    ref: main
    type: git
    trigger:
    - main   # <------------------ change this to the right branch

  - repository: RepoB # Alias/name used in the checkout step. It doesn't have to match the repository name
    endpoint: Endpoint
    name: Project-B/Repo-B # Project/repository name
    ref: main
    type: git
    trigger:
    - main

stages:
- stage: stage-1
  displayName: stage-1
  jobs:
  - job: job-1
  displayName: job-1
  steps:
  - checkout: RepoA
  - checkout: RepoB
  - script: script-testing

See Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline.
Edit
Authorization/security settings might prevent the build from being triggered:
Check the job authorization scope
Azure Pipelines provides a Limit job authorization scope to current project setting, that when enabled, doesn't permit the pipeline to access resources outside of the project that contains the pipeline. This setting can be set at either the organization or project level. If this setting is enabled, you won't be able to check out a repository in another project unless you explicitly grant access
Authorize access to the repositories
When you check out Azure Repos Git repositories other than the one containing the pipeline, you may be prompted to authorize access to that resource before the pipeline runs for the first time. These prompts are displayed on the pipeline run summary page.
See Troubleshooting authorization for a YAML pipeline.

Thanks you for answer. I fixed the repo-a typo. It was a mistake. Of course should be repo-b there.
Trigger: none on repo-a is intentional. It should trigger only with repo-B

You still didn't explain what nothing works mean. Is there any error?

@Mski added more details to my answer

Hello @Rui-Jarimba. I switched off job authorization but still I'm not able to trigger the pipeline with an update in main in repo-b.

@Mski run the build manually at least once, to ensure that you've authorized all the resources that are required.


What I want to achieve is to trigger this pipeline located in repo A to run when main of Repo-B will be updated.
They are in the same ADO Organization, on different projects. Same endpoint uses for both projects.

So, the pipeline is in project A and the yaml is in repo A. It will only be triggered by the changes in Repo B's main branch. In this case you only need to define the repository resource for Repo B, because the Repo A is the self repository. As they are in the same ADO Organization, on different projects, the endpoint is not needed. It is only needed when they are in a different organization.
Here is my test yaml file for your reference:
trigger: none     #the pipeline will not be triggered by Repo A
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: RepoB 
    name: projectname/RepoBname
    ref: main
    type: git
    trigger:
    - main       #the pipeline will be triggered by Repo B's main branch

stages:
- stage: 
  displayName: stage-1
  jobs:
  - job: 
    displayName: job-1
    steps:
    - checkout: self   #Repo A will be check out
    - checkout: RepoB  #Repo B will be check out
    - script: echo "script-testing"

You can also refer the trigger example from the document, where the self repository contains the YAML file and repositories A and B contain additional source code. It may help you better understand how the trigger works with repository resources.

Thank you for you answer but this will not work. Pipeline tab (as written on top of my question) is in repo-B. If you delete RepoA from resources it will not start the pipeline because location of yaml will be unknown.

Hi, could you please let me know what is the "Pipeline tab" in repo B? As you said "What I want to achieve is to trigger this pipeline located in repo A to run when main of Repo-B will be updated. " In my understanding, the pipeline is in project A and the yaml is in repo A. It will only be triggered by the changes in Repo B's main branch.  Is it correct? Please correct me if I am misunderstanding something. Thanks!
